# How can I use typescript in Aptana Studio?

Tags: typescript, aptana

I want to use typescript in ROR project, Aptana Studio 3.

Searched over the web for a plugin or a guide, but have found the only suggestion - add custom file type - ".ts", associate this file type with JavaScript editor and switch of errors.

Does anybody use TypeScript in Aptana Studio?

Comment: Most IDEs and editors don't have full typescript support, that will give you intellisense on interfaces, classes and definitions. Webstorm is probably the best cross platform IDE with intellisence for typescript. If you can live without intellisense, you can set up a grunt or gulp talk to compile your ts on save and output any compile errors/warnings. This is an IDE / editor agnostic solution.

Comment: Thank you, Martin, it seems it will be my way until i found more comfortable solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anybody use TypeScript in Aptana Studio?

Since its based on eclipse just use https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript

Comment: Thanks, it works. In spite of "Eclipse Kepler (4.3) is currently the only supported version" remark.

Answer (score 2):

For those who used **Standalone Version** instead of **Eclipse Plug-in Version**, there is no typescript support. Aptana is not listed on the [typescript editor support list](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Editor-Support).
Associating javascript editor with **`ts`** file type(step shown below) is less than perfect as it may sometime makes difficult to code due to inappropriate color highlight, but it will definitely work.

> Preferences -> Content Type -> Javascript -> add *.ts

Answer (score 1):

For full **`ts`** support there is typescript plugin for vim and emacs. As aptana also has its own terminal tab, we can use them on aptana tab.
[image]